# How to dinamically create a join in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to create a query that its builded dynamically on the base on what an user clicks on some filters. For example an user might want to search for all places that have both fish and sushi. I have the following tables:

categories:

```
+----+-------+
| id | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | pizza |
|  2 | fish  |
|  3 | sushi |
+----+-------+
```

places:

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| id |  Name  | Description  |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 | place1 | good place   |
|  2 | place2 | bad place    |
|  3 | place3 | nice place   |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

place_categories:

```
+----+----------+--------------+
| id | place_id | category_id  |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 |        1 |            2 |
|  2 |        1 |            3 |
|  3 |        2 |            1 |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

they have the following repataionships:

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :place_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :place_categories, foreign_key: 'place_id'
end


class Category < ApplicationRecord

      has_many :place_categories
      has_many :places, through: :place_categories

end

class PlaceCategory < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :place
  belongs_to :category

end
```

in my controller I receive the params array with different categories inside, such as:

```
Parameters: {"category_cusin"=>["fish", "sushi"]}
```

What I would like to do is to create a join for each category that is inside the params array, in a way that there is a 'category.name' attribute for each one of the join category tables. In this way I should be able to find all the places that have both the 'fish' and 'sushi' categories (in the case of the example).
The code I wrote in my controller is the following:

```
    filtered_places = Place.joins("INNER JOIN place_categories ON place.id = place_categories.place_id ").joins("INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = place_categories.category_id").select("places .*")

    if(!params['category_cusin'].blank?)
      filtered_places = filtered_place .select("categories.name AS category_name")
      params['category_cusin'].each do |category|
        raw_query = "INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = place_categories.category_id"
        filtered_places = filtered_places.joins(raw_query)
        filtered_places = filtered_places.where(categories: {name: category})
      end
    end
```

The problem is that the join always occurs on the table that has the same name. I should use an alias (category AS ....) for each of the item that exists in the params array, but I don't know how to dynamically create a query in Rails by considering this fact. I tried to build a string in this way:

```
if(!params['category_cusin'].blank?)
  filtered_places = filtered_places.select("categories.name AS category_name")
  count = 0
  params['category_cusin'].each do |category|
    raw_query = "INNER JOIN categories AS cat_" + count.to_s + " ON " + "cat_" + count.to_s + ".id = place_categories.category_id"
    filtered_places = filtered_places.joins(raw_query)
    filtered_places = filtered_places.where("cat_" + count.to_s +".name = " + category)
    count +=1
  end
end
```

but my server seems to be in a loop and not working well. What would be the best method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :place_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :place_categories
    
  def self.with_categories(categories)
    # limits the result to rows that have a least one match in the join table.
    joins(:categories)
      .where(categories: { name: categories })
      # By applying a GROUP and HAVING to the query you limit the result 
      # per group so it must have at least N number of matches
      .group(:id)
      .having(
         # Arel for COUNT(categories.*) >= ?
         Category.arel_table[Arel.star].count.gte(categories.length)
      )
  end 
end
```

Your controller is not the right place to do complex queries or complex parameter based filtering as they are hard to test. Its better to move this into the model layer or other objects that can be tested directly instead of through HTTP.

Instead your controller should really just contain the bare minimum:

```
def index
  @places = Place.all
  if params['category_cusin'].present?
    @places = @places.with_categories(params['category_cusin']) 
  end
end
```

If you want to create a set of search filters you should move that to a separate object that takes a base scope and a hash of parameters and returns a scope.

Comment: If you actually want to programatically build SQL that you can't build with the [ActiveRecord Query Interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) the answer is [Arel](https://devhints.io/arel). But I can't see anyhing in this question that actually warrants it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a scope on the `Place` model

```rb
scope :by_category, ->(*cats) { joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: cats }) }
```

And then call in your controller with:

```rb
@places = Place.by_category(params[:category_cusin])
```

If you're just wanting to find places that have those categories a scope would work just fine.